# Upgrading infotainment system in Peugeot

Tags: peugeot, infotainment

I have a second-hand Peugeot 208 1.2 PureTech Style (2017) with Apple CarPlay. Is it possible to upgrade it to have also Android Auto?

Comment: I don't know anything specifically about Peugeot but I've not seen any vehicles that support both Android Auto and Apple Carplay.  It seems to be one or the other so far.  It would be nice if there was a standard interface that allowed either to work but that would involve Apple and Google to cooperate.

Comment: Maybe it's relatively new, but my 2020 Buick has both and so does my sis in laws 2019 Buick. All of the 2020 cars I test drove have both.

Comment: @jwh20:  The last three cars I've owned have all supported both Android Auto and Apple Carplay.  They just detect which variety of phone has been connected to them.